# Problem publishing my Office Add-in to Azure, Office.js not fully loaded error, but works fine from localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365, azure-web-app-service

I've built and tested my add-in using Fabric React.  When I sideload it from `localhost:3000`, everything works fine.  I then created an Azure app services website to host it.  Updated the manifest XML file to point to the correct URL instead of `localhost:3000`. I updated all references from `Office.initialize` to `Office.onReady()`.  Still, every time I sideload the app from the Azure manifest I get the following error:

> Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()"
>   as part of its loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize"
>   function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this
>   page.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score -2):

I can’t reproduce the issue from my side.

I’d recommend you to debug your add-in via the steps in the following link: [Test and debug Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins)